# Visualvm does not detect applications on Mac

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, visualvm

When I run an application on netbeans, it wont be detected by VisualVM.

In local section it just shows VisualVM, GlassFish (pid 798) and Netbeans 6.9+ (pid 787).
I created two applications one on JSK 6 and the other on SDK 7 but neither one will be detected by VisualVm!

I am wondering why it does not detect either of applications.

The details of my visualvm are as following,

```
Version: 

1.6.0_65 (Build 110613); platform 110613-unknown-revn

System: 

Mac OS X (10.7.5) , x86_64 64bit

Java: 

1.6.0_65; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

Vendor: 

Apple Inc., http://www.apple.com/

Environment: 

MacRoman; en_US (visualvm)

Userdir: 

/Users/jack/Library/visualvm/6u23

Clusters: 

/System/Library/Java/Support/VisualVM.bundle/Contents/Home/platform
/System/Library/Java/Support/VisualVM.bundle/Contents/Home/visualvm
/System/Library/Java/Support/VisualVM.bundle/Contents/Home/profiler
```

Comment: Are they perhaps running as children of the NetBeans VM?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup no there is nothing under Netbeans

Comment: Test that you are not by accident using the Apple Java 6 JVM to run your programs and oracle java 7 to run jvisiualvm.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how to test it ?

Comment: Have a look at the system properties in the running program.

Comment: For me I was **just missing Java on local machine**...

Answer (score 1):

Just try to install oracle jdk and use embedded `jvisualvm`. It works for me

You can add env variables to `/etc/bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`  
launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $JAVA_HOME
```

and get path to oracle jdk: `echo $JAVA_HOME` or run jvisualvm from terminal